# Enable ribbon controls in specific documents C# vsto 2010

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I have an MS Office 2010 **application level** add-in, when it's loaded all ribbon controls in my custom tab are disabled.Then based on certain conditions I run this method to enable all the ribbon controls in my custom tab:

```
   public void EnableRibbonControls()
{
    IUnityContainer container = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUnityContainer>();
    RibbonTab customTab = container.Resolve<RibbonTab>();

    for (int i = 0; i < customTab.Groups.Count; i++)
    {
        IList<RibbonControl> controls = customTab.Groups[i].Items;
        foreach (var control in controls)
        {
            control.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this code enables the ribbon controls in the ribbon of **every** open Word document and not the specific one that I'm working on.

I would like to know whether the only way to fix this is by implementing a document level add-in or does someone know a work around for this in the application level add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently approach the same problem (in Excel) by setting a GUID as a [custom document property](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/view-or-change-the-properties-for-an-office-file-HA010354245.aspx) and then add an event handler on the Document.Activate event in my application level VSTO add-in. Whenever a document is activated, I check for the GUID and then hide or show the buttons accordingly.

Condensed Code Example:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    app.WorkbookActivate += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookActivateEventHandler(Application_WorkbookActivate);
    app.WorkbookDeactivate += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookDeactivateEventHandler(Application_WorkbookDeactivate);
}

private Guid _GetIdentity(Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
    try
    {
        // check for GUID
        Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties = Wb.CustomDocumentProperties;
        Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperty version = properties["_CustomIdentifier"];

        // parse the version for decide what features to activate
        Guid guidVersion;
        return Guid.TryParse(Convert.ToString(version.Value), out guidVersion) ? guidVersion : Guid.Empty;
    }
    catch
    {
        return Guid.Empty;
    }
}

void Application_WorkbookDeactivate(Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
   Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbon.btnButtonName.Visible = false;
}

void Application_WorkbookActivate(Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
    if(_GetIdentity(Wb) == {PRE-DEFINED-GUID})
    {
        Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbon.btnButtonName.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

My code is specific to Excel, you will need to check the docs what Word equivalent of the Activate/Deactivate events.

Disclaimer: This is only an extract of my actual code, may contain errors.